# Cannot access '/usr/local/

Tags: bash, permissions, chmod, mobile-broadband, huawei

Hello I was trying to install Huawei E173 driver by following steps that are available in https://www.ubuntu4u.com/howtos/how-install-huawei-e173-usb-modem-ubuntu-10041204-lts

When I executed `sudo bash ./install`
I received this error:
Local path is: `/usr/local/Movistar_3.5G`

```
Installing Movistar 3.5G...chmod: cannot access '/usr/local/Movistar_3.5G/config': No such file or directory
chmod: cannot access './driver/*': No such file or directory
./install: line 420: ./driver/install: No such file or directory
chmod: cannot access './sbin/*': No such file or directory
chmod: cannot access './hw_pppd': No such file or directory
chmod: cannot access './hw_pppd': No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat './hw_pppd': No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat '/usr/local/Movistar_3.5G/qtlib/lib*.so*': No such file or directory
grep: /usr/local/Movistar_3.5G/SysConfig.dat: No such file or directory
grep: /usr/local/Movistar_3.5G/SysConfig.dat: No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat '/usr/local/Movistar_3.5G/sbin/67hw_hook': No such file or directory
chmod: cannot access '/etc/pm/sleep.d/67hw_hook': No such file or directory
                                      [ done ]
```

And even if I executed `sudo chmod +x install` 
Nothing changed . What can I do to fix this error ?

Comment: It looks like you didn't `Go into the extracted folder`

Comment: It is quite unlikely that a driver built for Ubuntu 10.04 or 12.04 will ever compile successfully in any recent; that is, not end-of-life, version. Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Oh no I already extracted it , and the terminal was opened on it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think yo're typo of the string. Read the `readme.txt` first.

-----How to Install-----
You need login as root

1. Run `tar jxvf linux_install.tar.bz2`
2. Run `./install` in TERMINAL to install MobilePartner
   eg: # bash //install
3. If you had installed this software in your system before, you will get a prompt: "The software is exist, do you want overwrites? ([Y]/[N])", enter "y" to overwrites or "n" to exit.
4. If you do not had installed this software in your system before, you will get a prompt: "Please input the install path[/usr/local/Mobile_Partner]:". Then you can input install path(fullpath), or you may using the default path(/usr/local/Mobile_Partner) by press ENTER direct
5. Finish installing

-----How to run-----

- From shortcut in desktop
- Run MobilePartner in your install path
  eg: # //MobilePartner
- Plug in your device, it will run automatically (Not supported in Xandros)